# c++ class method that takes arbitrary number of callbacks and stores results

Tags: c++, callback, std

I've been trying to think of a way to have my class method take an arbitrary number of callback functions, run all of them, and then store the output. I think this works, but is there a way I can do this where I don't have to make the user wrap all of the callback functions into a vector? This also just feels messy. Feel free to mention other things that are not ideal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class MyObj{
public:
    // where I store stuff
    std::vector<double> myResults;

    // function that is called intermittently
    void runFuncs(const std::vector<std::function<double()> >& fs){
        if ( myResults.size() == 0){
            for( auto& f : fs){
                myResults.push_back(f());
            }
        }else{
            int i (0);
            for( auto& f : fs){
                myResults[i] = f();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    auto lambda1 = [](){ return 1.0;};
    auto lambda2 = [](){ return 2.0;};

    MyObj myThing;

    std::vector<std::function<double()> > funcs;
    funcs.push_back(lambda1);
    funcs.push_back(lambda2);
    myThing.runFuncs(funcs);

    std::cout << myThing.myResults[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << myThing.myResults[1] << "\n";

    std::vector<std::function<double()> > funcs2;
    funcs2.push_back(lambda2);
    funcs2.push_back(lambda1);
    myThing.runFuncs(funcs2);

    std::cout << myThing.myResults[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << myThing.myResults[1] << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What should happen if `runFuncs` is called twice, passing more callbacks the second time than the first? At the moment, your program exhibits undefined behavior in this case.

Comment: I'd use `.empty()` to decide if the vector was empty or not, but I think it would be better to just resize it to the number of callbacks and then assign the results in a for loop. There's no guarantee I see that if the vector is not empty that it's the right size.

Comment: This seems a little cleaner to me. *shrug* https://ideone.com/WN697O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
template <typename... Fs>
void runFuncs(Fs... fs) {
  myResults = std::vector<double>({fs()...});
}
```

Then you can call it as

```
myThing.runFuncs(lambda1, lambda2);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CTXRM98061)

Comment: ok this looks cool. It's a variadic template, right? What's going on with the part '{fs()...}' ? I guess it's just calling all the functions, but what's this called? And why does it need to be wrapped in curly braces?

Comment: [Parameter pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion), in a brace-init list. It's calling `vector`'s constructor taking `initializer_list`, as in `std::vector<double>({1.0, 2.0, 3.0})`. The expansion itself doesn't have to be enclosed in curly braces - those are part of initializer list syntax, not of pack expansion syntax.